# What does "therewith constitute" mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

This comes from Religion and Culture: Essays in Honor of Bernard Lonergan, S. J. by Bernard J. F. Lonergan:

> For Frankl's conception of the will to meaning as correlated
>   questioning and answering allows one to perceive the two essential
>   characteristics of the will to meaning as intentional: The will to
>   meaning is the basic orientation, similar to Lonergan's notion of
>   value, to question any value in order to each individual meanings.
>   When conceived in this manner the will to meaning can be said to set
>   up a horizon of unlimited possible answers that can be intended by an
>   unlimited number of questions. The free choices which a person makes
>   from the manifold values encountered intend and **therewith constitute**
>   the specific world of freedom of the person.

I often see therewith with a word preceding it as in "in conjunction therewith" which roughly means "in conjunction with (that)", but in this example, I am not sure what it means.

I suppose it means "and constitute with that the specific world of freedom of the person", but what does "that" refer to? The subject is "The free choices", so I am a bit perplexed. Roughly, it should translate to "The free choices which a person makes from the manifold values encountered constitute with that the specific world of freedom of the person", but I have still no idea what "that" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the following are essentially equivalent:

> intend and **thereby** constitute
>   intend and, **with that**, constitute
>   intend and **thereupon** constitute

The latter two synonyms are mentioned specifically in Merriam-Webster's definition of [**therewith**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/therewith):

> **1** : with that
>   **2** : THEREUPON, FORTHWITH

In the context of this particular passage, *forthwith* would not be a good synonym.

---

All of these words are mostly nonessential. The following on its own would convey the same effective meaning:

> intend and constitute